# How to switch another branch of the same repo in Visual Studio TFS

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, version-control, commit

I am working on a project with two different staging servers. Now There are two branches for that project and My question is how can I switch to another branch while the code is not committed of the first branch because of the progress. In the meantime if I get some work to change on another branch so how is it possible to switch during work? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to use the git stash command for that (you need to do it from the command line).

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html

Comment: Thanks @Dylan, will try this too & link is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git stash` like Dylan said, but it's also worth keeping in mind that you can commit whenever you want. You don't have to push that commit up to the remote right away.

When you come back to that branch, you can finish what you were doing and use `commit --amend` to combine the work you've just completed with the contents of the previous commit. Or you can continue to commit normally and just do an interactive rebase before pushing where you squash the "work in progress".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s possible to switch between branches when there has uncommitted works on each  branch.

But one thing to note: you should notice which stash work to apply if you both stash works on two branches. Details as below example:

Assume you have unfinished work in `master` branch, while you want switch to `dev` branch. Then you can use `git stash` to store the uncommitted work on `master` branch. And the item in stack (`git stash list`) as:

```
stash@{0} WIP on master: sha-1 message
```

Then you can switch to `dev` branch (`git checkout dev`) and make changes. If you also need to switch back to `master` branch while keeping the uncommitted work in `dev` branch. Then you can also use `git stash` to store the changes on `dev` branch, and the stack (`git stash list`) will be:

```
stash@{0} WIP on dev: sha-1 message
stash@{1} WIP on master: sha-1 message
```

Now there has two stash works:

- If you want to continue the unfinished work on `master` branch you should apply the work `stash@{1}` by `git stash apply stash@{1}`.
- If you want to continue the unfinished work on `dev` branch you should apply the work `stash@{0}` by `git stash apply stash@{0}`. Since `git stash apply` default apply the latest work, so you can also use `git stash apply` to apply the changes on `dev` branch.

More details about git stash, you can refer [stashing in git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing).

Comment: Thanks @Marina, I'll try this in future. Right now the work has been done on a single branch. Thanks again.